# strict mode to avoid type conversion

Tags: mysql

Is there any sql mode that will return an error instead of implicitly converting the string to integer?

```
mysql> select * from todel ;
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    1 | abc    |
|    2 | xyz    |
|    0 | ABCxyz |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I expect an error message instead of a row with id 0

```
mysql> select * from todel where id = 'abc';
+------+--------+
| id   | name   |
+------+--------+
|    0 | ABCxyz |
+------+--------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'abc' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Alternatively you could migrate to a database which would refuse such a statement ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your concerns, but it's for this very reason you should *never* have an id set to `0`. In the long run I think you should reconsider your table rows before the behavior which isn't a problem in ideal situations. I haven't found anything relevant to this through a little searches, and that's probably because it's probably not a problem unless you make it one.

Apart from that, you *could* read relevant column data and act accordingly in php/whatev. From the table `COLUMNS` in `information_schema`, you can filter by `TABLE_SCHEMA` (database), `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` to get `DATATYPE` (double). If the column you're changing has a certain `DATATYPE`, let the script give error before running the MySQL query.

Another way to do it would simply be to convert input before parsing:

```
if ( ! is_numeric($id))
    $id = 'NULL';
```

To prevent incorrect `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s, you already [have that mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables).

---

In the end I can't come up with many practical ways that this strict mode you're after would benefit the MySQL users.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`STRICT_ALL_TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables) sql mode:

```
set @@GLOBAL.sql_mode  = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
set @@SESSION.sql_mode = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES";
```

However it works just on write operations:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> insert into test.test values ( "abc", "lol" );
--------------
insert into test.test values ( "abc", "lol" )
--------------

ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: 'abc' for column 'id' at row 1
```

There is no such thing to disable implicit conversions for read queries; instead you can just check if there are warnings and if yes, just free the result, abort the statement, and threat those warnings as errors.

Comment: It's not about the INSERT, it's about the comparison `integer_column = string_literal`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it doesnt have to be insert, it can be update, replace, whatever write operation. butread operation like SELECT will always implicitly convert between data types.

Comment: So you are saying that MariaDB with `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` will reject a statement with an error that uses `where id = 'abc'` (with `id` being an `integer` column).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes as long as the statement will update/write data to the table. It's also mysql not only mariadb.

Comment: I'm not talking about updating/writing data, **only** about *comparing* values. The problem is not about writing it's about reading and comparing values.